# silex validator using last constraint from previous collection item

Tags: validation, symfony, silex

based on the [tutorial](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/validator.html#validating-associative-arrays) for validation in silex i've created a constraint:

```
    $constraint = new Assert\Collection([
        'token' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Length(['min' => Constant::TOKEN_LENGTH, 'max' => Constant::TOKEN_LENGTH]),
        ],
        'languageCode' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Choice(['choices' => [Constant::LANGUAGE_CODE_DE, Constant::LANGUAGE_CODE_EN]])
        ],
        'startDate' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Date()
        ],
        'endDate' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
            new Assert\Date()
        ],
        'duration' => [
            new Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(['value' => 1])
        ],
    ]);
```

which should match the following structures (here from json):

```
{
    "token": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
    "languageCode": "DE",
    "startDate": "2016-01-01",
    "endDate": "2016-01-05",
    "duration": 1
}
```

and

```
{
    "token": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
    "languageCode": "DE",
    "startDate": "2016-01-01",
    "endDate": "2016-01-05"
}
```

While first example is validated as expected, the second (with the optional duration) will respond in a strange behavior: the constraints from "endDate" where used:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList)[154]
  private 'violations' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation)[158]
          private 'message' => string 'This field is missing.' (length=22)
          private 'messageTemplate' => string 'This field is missing.' (length=22)
          private 'parameters' => 
            array (size=1)
              '{{ field }}' => string '"duration"' (length=10)
          private 'plural' => null
          private 'root' => 
            array (size=4)
              'token' => string 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855' (length=64)
              'languageCode' => string 'DE' (length=2)
              'startDate' => string '2016-01-01' (length=10)
              'endDate' => string '2016-01-05' (length=10)
          private 'propertyPath' => string '[duration]' (length=10)
          private 'invalidValue' => null
          private 'constraint' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date)[136]
              public 'message' => string 'This value is not a valid date.' (length=31)
              public 'payload' => null
              public 'groups' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Default' (length=7)
          private 'code' => string '2fa2158c-2a7f-484b-98aa-975522539ff8' (length=36)
          private 'cause' => null
```

I don't see the any reason for that....

Answer (score 0):

try to add parameter `allowMissingFields`

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    'allowMissingFields' => true,
    'fields' => [asserts...]
]);
```